# Passing a variable from a Javascript to a Servlet without using JQuery

Tags: javascript, servlets

I have multiple dynamically generated links on a JSP page (JSTL).
I want to submit the id and name of the clicked link to a Servlet using Javascript.

Here's a snippet from my JSP page:

```
    <c:otherwise>
     <td><a name="${rootBean.beanprojname}" id="${rootBean.beanprojname}"       
         onclick="func(this.name,this.id)" href="#">${rootBean.beanprojname}</a><br> 

        <a name="${rootBean.beanprojname}" id="More Details" onclick="func(this.name,this.id)" href="#">More Details</a></td>
    </c:otherwise>
```

and in my javascript:

```
function func(name,id)
{
    //What to write here to pass the name and id to a servlet (without using JQuery)?
}
```

**P.S: There are no form tags on my page.**

Comment: Do you have to use JavaScript?  I mean, the link can just go directly to your servlet and your servlet can respond with a redirect to the target page.  That's how Google does it.

Comment: Well it's a question just out of curiosity ..
I know it can easily be achieved by the use of JQuery..
Is it possible to achieve the same using only Javascript too?

Comment: JQuery *is* [written in] JavaScript, so yes, it is possible.

Comment: Pure Javascript..
not using any libraries..

Comment: Not sure understood my first comment, sorry, you don't even need JavaScript, why would you insist on it?  You can just do it in HTML, if you don't want to leave the page, then target the links to a hidden IFRAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it's working!

In my javascript:

```
function func(name,id)
{
    var redirect="http://localhost:9090/HCLRMS/empavl?pname="+name+"&pid="+id;
    window.open(redirect,"_self");

}
```

In my servlet:

```
 String fid=request.getParameter("pid");
 String fname=request.getParameter("pname");
```